# Google Drive Realtime API - Read-only users (limits)

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am developing an application with Google Realtime API that will have to handle a large number of concurrent read-only users. Is there a specific way to declare that a user should open the concurrent model in a read-only mode? Is there a limit on the number of concurrent read-only users on a single model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the document is only shared with them with read, it will open in readonly mode.

There is a limit to concurrent users, regardless if readonly or not of ~50.

If you need many more than that, consider using an exported version + in memory mode to show them a snapshot of the model.

Comment: Is there a way to enlarge that limit to, say, some hundreds of users by requesting it through the Cloud Console interface?

Comment: No, unfortunately its not a simple limit to lift.